# Highcharts Date.UTC does not work properly for real data

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

I've built something like this. I get my data from the server, put it in an object called series, and pass it to 'series' in Highcharts code block. Basically, for every staff, there will be a date, and my default value(Y-Axis) is '1' for now. However, I can't get dates on the chart as expected even if it looks that I had correct data and did correct parsing. Unexpectedly, I get my millisecond values as Y-axis values, which does not make any sense, and every staff has a default date, which is 1 January. **(For ex., staff 1, 1 January, x-axis value = 1554422400000)**

I get dates like this, **19-02-2019 17:32**. Then I split them, and use it like this,
**([Date.UTC(parseInt(yearsplit[0]), datesplit[1]-1, parseInt(datesplit[0])), 1])**
which looks exactly the same format in Highcharts, **([Date.UTC(1971, 2, 16), 0.86])**

```
var responsePromise = $http.post('statistics/getAllProtocolRecords', data, null);

responsePromise.success(function (dataFromServer, status, headers, config) {

    var series = [{
        name: "",
        data: []
    }];

    dataFromServer.protocolRecords.forEach((data) => {

        var datesplit = data.checkupDate.split("-");
        var yearsplit = datesplit[2].split(" ");

        series.push({
            name: data.staff,
            data: [Date.UTC(parseInt(yearsplit[0]), datesplit[1]-1, parseInt(datesplit[0])), 1]
        })
    });
    series.shift();

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Toplam Muayene Kaydı (' + sysrefHcCheckupType + ')'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Tarih'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Toplam Muayene (Gün)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:%f} '
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        colors: ['#00bdff', '#FF0700', '#df0300', '#ff0700', '#c0df00'],
        series: series
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried what epoch your `Date.UTC(parseInt(yearsplit[0]), datesplit[1]-1, parseInt(datesplit[0]))` returns?

Comment: Try to open Developer Tools (Really important to learn if you want to be a developer) and debug your code using breakpoints and such, so you can know what is exactly happening at runtime.

Comment: It returns me those values; 1550620800, 1550534400, 1550620800, 1550620800

Comment: Highcharts needs the values in milliseconds, those are seconds. If you do `new Date(1550620800)` you will see what actually happens. Something weird you are doing as Date.UTC returns the values in milliseconds, and what you get are seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that I'd made a little mistake in push function. In series.push, 'data' should like this, surrounded by array brackets:

```
data: [
   [ Date.UTC(parseInt(yearsplit[0]), parseInt(datesplit[1])-1, parseInt(datesplit[0])), 1]
   ]
```